# Declaring a cursor after begin in oracle forms 10g

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am writing the following code block :

```
select companyid into compid from person where signedin = 1;
cursor getpending is select serviceid from servnego where companyid = compid and confirmed = 0;
open getpending;
loop
    exit when getpending%notfound;
    fetch getpending into servid;
    select servname into s from service where id = servid;
    add_list_element('homeadmin1.listpendingservice', counter2,s,s);
    counter2 := counter2 + 1;
end loop;
```

This is a part of the code that is inside the begin/end. The cursor getpending depends on the value of the variable compid from the select statement right before it. When compiling I get an error on the cursor line : "Encountered the symbol getpending when expecting one of the following : ...", so there is an error on the declaration of the cursor in the begin part. How can I solve the issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cursor is like any other variable, it needs to be declared in the declaration section. However, you can declare it with a parameter...

```
declare
    ....
    cursor getpending (p_compid number) is 
        select serviceid from servnego 
        where companyid = p_compid 
        and confirmed = 0;
declare
    select companyid into compid 
    from person 
    where signedin = 1;
    open getpending (compid );
    loop
        fetch getpending into servid;
        exit when getpending%notfound;
        select servname into s 
        from service 
        where id = servid;
        add_list_element('homeadmin1.listpendingservice', counter2,s,s);
        counter2 := counter2 + 1;
    end loop;
    close getpending;
```

Note that you need to test for cursor `%notfound` *after* you execute the fetch. Otherwise you will get an error when the cursor is exhausted. Also, remember to close the cursor after you exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the first query within the `CURSOR`. Also note that the 
`exit when` statement should come after the `FETCH`

```
 DECLARE
    CURSOR getpending IS
      SELECT serviceid
      FROM   servnego
      WHERE  companyid IN (SELECT companyid 
                            FROM   person
                           WHERE  signedin = 1)
             AND confirmed = 0;
--declare  s and counter2 here appropriately.
BEGIN
    OPEN getpending;

    LOOP
        FETCH getpending INTO servid;

        exit WHEN getpending%NOTFOUND;

        SELECT servname
        INTO   s
        FROM   service
        WHERE  id = servid;

        Add_list_element('homeadmin1.listpendingservice', counter2, s, s);

        counter2 := counter2 + 1;
    END LOOP;
END;

/
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible, I recommend using a cursor for-loop. Oracle automatically optimizes cursor for-loops by bulk-binding the fetches, which reduces the round-trips to the database and thus improves performance. Also, try to do as much work in a single SQL statement as you can:

```
FOR aRow IN (SELECT c.SERVNAME
               FROM SERVNEGO s
               INNER JOIN PERSON p
                 ON s.COMPANYID = p.COMPID
               INNER JOIN SERVICE c
                 ON c.ID = s.SERVICE_ID
               WHERE s.CONFIRMED = 0 AND
                     p.SIGNEDIN = 1)
LOOP
  add_list_element('homeadmin1.listpendingservice',
                   counter2, aRow.SERVNAME, aRow.SERVNAME);
  counter2 := counter2 + 1;
END LOOP;
```

This also helps get rid of unneeded temporary variables which contribute to problems related to values being stored in multiple places, which is never a good thing.

Best of luck.